# Path on File Server is not accessible from a windows application written in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows application (not deployed, I am debugging it in my machine) written in vb, that is supposed to download a file from a server. But the application is returning a "False" when doing the File.Exists("path on the FileServer").

1. I can access the path on FileServer from my windows explorer and see the file.
2. I have given full control to everyone at a parent directory level on file server, but still does not work.
3. I have removed "read only" check at a parent level directory on file server, does'nt help.
4. I have written a console application in vb and c# to check if the path on FileServer is accessible. It works here. File.Exists returns a True here.

Looks like the path on fileserver is not getting detected from the windows application alone. Please help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Directory.Exists return a true for the parent directory? Are you sure you're checking the same path in your app and the c# console app? How about writing the file and see where it ends up.

Comment: Post the code that is creating the path string and doing the checking. My guess you have a faulty path string.

Comment: Directory.Exists on parent directory returns "False" as well....from the windows application. The path is correct, because I have coped the same string and pasted in console application (returns true) and file explorer (can see the file). I have tried to create a text file from the console application in the path, it is getting created. The path is not working only with the windows application.

Comment: Have you tried running the application in administrator mode?